# PowerShell dataGridView - Copy only one Row into an other dataGridView

Tags: powershell, user-interface, datagridview, copy, row

I´ve got a very short question about the "dataGridView".

I´m developing with the Microsoft PowerShell and I want to copy one Row (from `$dataGridView1`) to the other (`$dataGridView2`).

With this Code I can only Copy the Value of the last focused Cell. 
I´ve tried to make this for a whole Row, but it´s only working with Cells.

Here is my Code:

```
**$btnListeAdd.Add_Click({

        $Row = $dataGridView1.Rows[ $dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex ]
        $dataGridView2.Rows.Add( $dataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value )
        $dataGridView1.Rows.Remove( $Row ) })
$tabListe.Controls.Add($btnListeAdd)**
```

Only the market Cell in $dataGridView1 (similar Column 1 or 2) will be cloned in Column1 in `$dataGridView2` - in a extra Row, yey.

Thanks for helping me.
Please show mercy. It´s my first day with the PowerShell.

Kind regards,
Marcel L.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate through the values in the cells. Try this:

```
$btnListeAdd.Add_Click({
    $Row = $dataGridView1.Rows[$dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex]
    $values = @($Row.Cells|ForEach-Object{$_.Value})
    $dataGridView2.Rows.Add( $values )
    $dataGridView1.Rows.Remove( $Row ) })
$tabListe.Controls.Add($btnListeAdd)
```

You might be better off databinding each DataGridView to an ArrayList and then just updating the ArrayLists. Check [Hey Scripting Guy](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2010/03/22/hey-scripting-guy-march-22-2010.aspx) for an example.

Comment: This was only for learning.
Later there will be an Exchange-Server DB behind it (Edding distributionlists and members).
And it´s a nice Website ( [Scripting Guy](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2010/03/22/hey-scripting-guy-march-22-2010.aspx) )